# Alternitive for macro with return statement

Tags: swift, swift3, macros

In my MotionManager wrapper class I have this one code snippet that repeats for each of it's function. This code is there to make the app runable on simulator without otherwise required gyroscope in device. The code snippet I'm using looks like this:

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    return // Do nothing if in simulator
#endif
```

I would like to replace this code with a single line of code stating clearly what it does and isn't so ugly. If I was writing this in C++ I would simply use macro that would look something like this:

```
#define skipIfSimulator #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE /
                            return /
                        #endif
```

So instead of this:

```
func foo() {
   #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
       return // Do nothing if in simulator
   #endif
   ...
}
```

There would be this:

```
func foo() {
   skipIfSimulator
   ...
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this while adding preferably no overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a pretty poor work-around. But it can satisfy your need.

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
BOOL const kIsSimulator = NO;
#else
BOOL const kIsSimulator = YES;
#endif

#define SIM(x) if (kIsSimulator) {x; return;}
```

**Usage:**

```
SIM(`any_statement`);
```

**Example usage:**

```
SIM(NSLog(@"on Simulator"));
or,
SIM(); // No statement at all
```

**Self contained example:** ***`Objective-C`***

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
BOOL const kIsSimulator = NO;
#else
BOOL const kIsSimulator = YES;
#endif

#define SIM(x) if (kIsSimulator) {x; return;}

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self printAMessage];
}

- (void)printAMessage {
    SIM(NSLog(@"on Simulator"));
    NSLog(@"on iPhone");
}
@end
```

Unfortunately can't reproduce same with ***Swift***.